# Testing Sinatra API endpoint with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a simple Sinatra with an endpoint "/status" which returns a JSON that looks like this:

`curl http://localhost`

`{"stats":{"hostname":"Home","cpu":null,"disk":null,"ram":null,"check_time":null}}`

I am trying to write tests in RSpec to test if the app responds to this endpoint and whether the endpoint returns proper data in a proper format.
The endpoint looks like this:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  @@stat = Stat.new

  def self.stat
    @@stat
  end

  get '/status' do
    { stats: @@stat.to_h }.to_json
  end
end
```

The Stat class looks like this:

```
class Stat
  attr_accessor :hostname, :cpu, :disk, :ram, :check_time

  @@stat = []

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    hostname = `hostname`.strip
    @hostname = hostname
    @cpu = attributes[:cpu]
    @disk = attributes[:disk]
    @ram = attributes[:ram]
    @check_time = attributes[:check_time]
  end

  def to_h
    {
     hostname: hostname,
     cpu: cpu,
     disk: disk,
     ram: ram,
     check_time: check_time
    }
  end
end
```

When I do `curl http://localhost` it returns this:

`{"stats":{"hostname":"Home","cpu":null,"disk":null,"ram":null,"check_time":null}}`

I have a problem in a test where I expect this format but get something else:

```
 describe "GET /status" do
    let(:response) { get "/status" }

    it "returns proper JSON" do
      expect(response.body).to eq({"stats":{"hostname":"Home","cpu":null,"disk":null,"ram":null,"check_time":null}})
    end
 end
```

First, it does not like `null` (although `curl` command returns `null`). If I change it to `nil` then I get this:

```
expected: {:stats=>{:hostname=>"Home", :cpu=>nil, :disk=>nil, :ram=>nil, :check_time=>nil}}
got: "{\"stats\":{\"hostname\":\"Home\",\"cpu\":null,\"disk\":null,\"ram\":null,\"check_time\":null}}"
```

When I do 
`puts response.body` I get this:

`{"stats":{"hostname":"Home","cpu":null,"disk":null,"ram":null,"check_time":null}}`

How do I fix this? Sorry if this question may seem improper for some but I still learn to test with RSpec.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused by JSON response and Ruby's hash. Your api returns json and in test you have to compare either two json strings or two hashes. For example, to compare using json you can do:

```
expect(response.body).to eq({ stats: { hostname: "Home", cpu: nil, disk: nil, ram: nil, check_time: nil } }.to_json)
```

Or with hashes:

```
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq({ "stats" => { "hostname" => "Home", "cpu" => nil, "disk" => nil, "ram" => nil, "check_time" => nil } })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize that JSON is a String. You've made my day!